# Why is a question about being underpaid attracting downvotes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17202/im-underpaid-when-and-how-to-approach-this-with-my-boss

In this question he articulates his position clearly, and asks clear questions, yet it has attracted at least 3 down votes.

Granted his question could be quite a lot more concise,  to avoid the 'tl;dr' factor of a relatively simple question.

Why is this question attracting downvotes? Is it because it's been marked duplicate?

Comment: This question, since it's a duplicate, is a good candidate for editing, once enough time passes where we're sure the asker won't make edits. In general, closed duplicates can be edited to help attract more visitors to the site and to the canonical post. I also comment on these and suggest the asker look at the other answers and, if the problem isn't solved, edit to further differentiate from the duplicate.

Answer (score 8):

I didn't DV it, but as I said in a comment before seeing that, put this into the "Ask a question" box:

> I'm underpaid! When, and how, to approach this with my boss?

It's annoying to me when people post a duplicate question after seeing a very clear duplicate. This to me says "I can't be bothered to look at the questions the site said are related and one in fact turns out to be the identical question I am asking, but, it'd be nice if the community answered mine instead!"

Answer (score 0):

Questions seeking advice on what job to take, what skills to learn, how to negotiate a raise based on your specific skillset, etc. are off-topic as the answers are rarely useful to anyone else.